# Why does my store brand butter break apart

Tags: butter, safety

I've been buying my store brand butter for a while now.   For the past while, I've noticed that when I open the butter and slice it, it falls apart in a chunky way.  Sometimes as if there were a circle in the middle running long ways.   What's going on with it?  It tastes fine, but I'm worried it's not good.

Comment: Are you storing the butter in a way that creates a heat differential, eg with one side of the package containing the freezing back wall of your fridge, while the other hugs the fridge light (bonus points if the fridge light switch is broken leaving the light on all the time)?

Comment: Actually I've noticed something like this too. I'll go to put a cold stick of butter in a bowl to soften, and the outer "shell" of the butter sticks to the wrapper. If I poke at the stick (because of course I would), I can peel/tear sheets of butter off longways. No idea why, but it's not just one side of the butter. It's outside vs. inside in my case. That said, while weird, I've never had any adverse effects from using that kind of butter. My guess was that it had something to do with moisture content? But....

Comment: The placement doesn't seem to matter in this case.   And it seems to only be the store brand.

Comment: It could be the manufacturing process that was changed: extrusion through cylindrical pipes where the butter gets cooled inside the pipes and then pressed into a cuboid form would result in the texture you describe.  As to food safety: it would actually *improve*  the safety (as the butter is cooled quicker than the old process, where the cooling takes place afterwards.)  Pure speculation though as we have no brand name, picture, ... so a comment and not an answer.